# Appengine datastore not updating multiple records

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

```
        votergroup = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE lastname = :1", 'AGEE')

    for voter in votergroup:
        voter.email = 'testemail@testemail.com'
    db.put(votergroup)
```

The above code doesn't seem to be updating the records as it shows in the appengine documentation.  I also tried using a query object to no avail.  I know votergroup is pulling records, because I did a count on the object when debugging and it showed 10 records.  In fact, before the db.put, I looped through voter.email, and it seems like the variable was set.  However, the change never seems to make it back to the db.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `fetch()` on the query you create with `db.Query()` to have it return a list of entities.  You can then call `put(list_of_entities)` to persist them all. That looks like this:

```
voters = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE lastname = :1", 'AGEE').fetch(10)

for voter in voters:
    voter.email = 'testemail@testemail.com'
db.put(voters)
```

If you don't call `fetch()` on the query, you can still iterate over the results, and a datastore RPC will be made to retrieve small batches as they are needed. Calling `put()` on the query doesn't do anything, but you can still perform actions on each entity inside the loop.

```
voters_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE lastname = :1", 'AGEE')

for voter in voters_query:
    voter.email = 'testemail@testemail.com'
    voter.put()
```

Note that this does one datastore calls for each entity, plus one call for each batch being iterated over.  It's much better to use `fetch()` unless you don't know how many items will be returned.

You can use [cursors](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors) to break fetches up into larger chunks. I believe, though I can't find any proof, that `fetch()` has a limit of 1000 entities.

Comment: That's so peculiar - so is the appengine documentation wrong?  Check this out: https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html

About halfway down you'll see the example code that I mimicked

if users.get_current_user():
    user_pets = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE owner = :1",
                            users.get_current_user())
    for pet in user_pets:
        pet.spayed_or_neutered = True

    db.put(user_pets)

Comment: That looks like a typo. Later on in the GqlQuery section (https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_Entities_Using_a_Query) they use `fetch()` before iterating over `results`.

Comment: Is there any way to have a limitless "fetch".  In this circumstance there were only 10 records, but I really don't want to necessarily limit it.  Is my only option breaking it off into smaller jobs, like mapper?

Thank you so much btw.  I banged my head for almost 4 hours trying to figure out what in the hell I was doing wrong.  How aggravating!  I wonder who I would speak to about getting that documentation fixed - it would seem to me that this page would be one of the most referenced parts of the documentation.

Comment: Updated my answer to be a much more complete answer. Short answer: use cursors.

Comment: minor nitpick: an RPC won't be made for each iteration; entities are fetched in small batches.  I believe you'll get an RPC for each 10 iterations.

Comment: @Wooble Good to know. The `put()` inside the loop will still be called for each iteration though, so using `fetch()` is still a much better option.

Comment: One error: calling db.put() on a Query doesn't do nothing - it's worse than nothing. It'll iterate over every result the query has to return, storing them all back to the datastore unmodified!

Comment: Also, the 1000 entity limit on fetch() was removed a few releases ago (although you can still get a DeadlineExceeded fetching too many entities at once...)

Comment: @Nick wow, that seems...bad. Shouldn't it at least do nothing, or better yet raise an error?

Comment: @Jason No, because passing an iterator to db.put is a perfectly valid operation - for example, if you had a generator function that produces entities to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
votergroup = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE lastname = :1", 'AGEE')

for voter in votergroup:
    voter.email = 'testemail@testemail.com'
    voter.put()
```

I don't think there is a way to do mass edits with the app engine.

Comment: `put()` takes a list of entities, and persists them all: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#put

Comment: @Jason Hall: I stand corrected. Last time I tried something like that it simply didn't work and i wasn't able to find it in the docs.