# GAE - find duplicates - Changing model schema then updating <missing> bool field gives <null> instead of True/False

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After adding to my GAE model a `Boolean` column `isDuplicate = db.BooleanProperty()`, I am trying in the python code to find and mark the duplicate field with :

```
records = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field1 = :1", value)
if records.count() > 1:
   records[0].isDuplicate = True
   records[0].put()
```

But then the record has its field1's value changed to `<null>` instead of `True`, while the others have `<missing>` in the field1's value.

Any idea why `isDuplicate` is set to `null` instead of `True` ?

Plus when I check in the Datastore Viewer the updated record, the field `isDuplicate` type is set to `null`.

**Update**

This code now works :

```
records = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field1 = :1", value)
if records.count() > 1:
    results = records.fetch(limit=None)
    for record in results:
        record.isDuplicate = True
    db.put(results)
```

Comment: think it should be `len(records) > 0`

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  records is a query object,  it doesn't support indexing.  You need to run or fetch.

Comment: Thanks, @TimHoffman, fetch was necessary. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553481/appengine-datastore-not-updating-multiple-records) helped too.